# Android: Adjusting the Width of the Selector in SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java

Tags: android, tabs

I'm trying to adjust the width of the selector line (or strip) which is placed beneath a tab, according to the size of the text within the tab. So, I want that the length of the strip should also become as same as the length of the text. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed it, instead of setting padding for the TextView inside the `createDefaultTabView()`method, I set custom `LayoutParams` using margins. The modified code is as follows:

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    int padding = (int) (14 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    params.setMargins(padding, padding, padding, 0);

    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
            outValue, true);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    textView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, padding);
    return textView;
}
```

The number 14 here can be changed according to your spacing requirements, but as per the question, the selector adjusts its width according to the tab's text's width.